# Auto focus not working on react native formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik

I am using [formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik) and [react-native-formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-formik) to create form. I am using my custom component for textinput in formik form.

My custom component code :

```js
// import statements ...

class FormInput extends Component {

  focus = () => { this.textInputField.focus(); }

  render() {
    const {props} = this;
    return (
      <TextInput
        {...this.props}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        ref={(ref) => { this.textInputField = ref }}
        style={{ height: 50, borderWidth: 1, margin: 5 }}
      />  
    )
  }
}

export default FormInput
```

Then I create Form from below code :

```js
const FormInput2 = compose(
  handleTextInput,
  withNextInputAutoFocusInput
)(FormInput);
const Form = withNextInputAutoFocusForm(View);
```

Then I have created original form as below :

```js
<ScrollView
  style={styles.container}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
  keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
>
  <Formik
    initialValues={{ firstName: '', email: '', password: '' }}
    onSubmit={values => { }}
    validationSchema={signUpValidationSchema}
    render={({ values, handleChange, errors, setFieldTouched, touched, isValid, handleSubmit }) => (
      <Form>
        <FormInput2
          icon="user"
          placeholder="First Name"
          value={values.firstName}
          onChangeText={handleChange('firstName')}
          onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('firstName')}
        />
        {touched.firstName && errors.firstName && (
          <CText style={{ fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.firstName}</CText>
        )}

        {/* 
          ...
          ...
          Others Fiels 
        */}
        <Button
          title="SIGN UP"
          disabled={!isValid}
          color={Colors.primary}
          onPress={handleSubmit}
        />
      </Form>
    )}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

But, I am getting `done` on each and every field keyboard return type. If I press done then form submit method fires.

Can anyone help me how can I implement auto focus ?

I have also tried exporting my custom component as below, but it is also not working :

```js
export default withFormikControl(FormInput)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is also having the same error then here is the solution...

Custom component should have `name` property and the order of the component should be the same as `initialValues`.

Means if `initialValues` as below :

```js
initialValues={{ firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '', phone: '', password: '', confirmPassword: '' }}
```

Then first should be `firstName` field then `lastName`, `email` and so on...

So I added `name` prop in custom component and worked autofocus.

```js
<FormInput2
  icon="user"
  placeholder="First Name"
  value={values.firstName}
  label="First Name"
  name="firstName" // added this
  type="name"
  onChangeText={handleChange('firstName')}
  onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('firstName')}
/>
{
  touched.firstName && errors.firstName && (
    <CText style={{ fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.firstName}</CText>
  )
}

<FormInput2
  label="Last Name"
  name="lastName" // added this
  type="name"
  icon="user"
  placeholder="Last Name"
  value={values.lastName}
  onChangeText={handleChange('lastName')}
  onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('lastName')}
/>
{
  touched.lastName && errors.lastName && (
    <CText style={{ fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.lastName}</CText>
  )
}
```